# Magento 2.3.4 theme use different logo file for mobile and larger screens

Tags: magento2.3, javascript, jquery, mobile

I need to use **2 different logo files**, one for mobile and one for desktop view.
I have **one single custom theme** (parent is luma) and I am wondering how to achieve this by using jquery and/or CSS.
Is there a good way to do that using the mediaCheck function?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can achieve this with css.